# Why do i get MFC runtime error when I am not using MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, runtime-error, visual-studio-2005, citrix

I am trying to run client virtual driver dll (in essence this is not a driver it is user mode code). This dll is loaded by the Citrix Client which has manifests for CRT, MFC, MFCLOC all pointing to Visual Studio 2005.

I have linked my dll to the exact version of C++ runtime found in the manifest files installed with the Citrix Client.

Now, my DLL is pure win32 code with no MFC calls, yet I am getting 'error generating activation context for MFC80.dll'

---

### Msg

Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\MFC80.DLL".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC.MANIFEST" on line 5. Component identity found in manifest does not match the identity of the component requested. Reference is Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0". Definition is Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762". Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Comment: So, did you "use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis"?

Comment: Got the same error with slight more info in SxSTrace

Comment: INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
 ERROR: Component identity found in manifest does not match the identity of the component requested. Reference is Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0". Definition is Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Installing the runtime listed in the SxSTrace, solved the problem.

Comment: The root cause was simply that the version installed was older than the version required. VC80 had a number of updates to the runtime.